# How do I find multiple substrings in a string in php

Tags: php

I have these tables. In the first table I have the transaction ID and the products bought in that transaction.

```
  TID         Products
   1           1,2,5 
   2            2,4 
   3            2,3 
   4           1,2,4 
   5            1,3 
   6            2,3 
   7            1,3 
   8          1,2,3,5 
   9           1,2,3
```

What I want to do to this data is count the number of times an itemset occurs in the Products column. For example the itemset {1,2} is found 4 times in the Products column, there is no problem there, but 1,3 in only found 2 times but as it's seen in the Products column it appears 4 times.

```
ItemSet     Sup. count 
  1,2            4 
  1,3            2 
  1,4            0 
  1,5            0 
  2,3            4 
  2,4            2 
  2,5            1 
  3,4            0 
  3,5            1 
  4,5            0
```

This is the php code that I used to find matches in the Sup. count column. if I make it find all coincidences in the itemset when I get to two digit numbers like 12 or more it will say that it found 1 and 2 again that is why I placed the boundary. So I am stuck at this place.

```
$result_support =  array_fill ( 0 , $count_itemsets , 0 );
$count_result_array = count($result_array);

for($i = 0; $i < $count_itemsets; $i++){
    for($j = 0; $j < $count_result_array; $j++){
        $string = $result_array[$j];
        if (preg_match('~\\b' . $result_itemset[$i] . '\\b~i', $string, $m)) {
            $result_support[$i] = $result_support[$i] + 1;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: explode Products by `,` and check if there is product you looking for in that new array

Comment: If you have that in tables (relational DB), then you're solving [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You should not have such kind of data in the first place. Use separate table to store your related data. That is entire purpose of relational DB

Comment: The only table in the database is TID and Products. since I am getting all the combinations possible when there are 2 itemsets then when there are 3, 4 and so on.

Comment: Hey can u get me your answer and the required answer separately

Answer (score 0):

```
$array1 = array(
   1=>           '1,2,5',
   2 =>           '2,4', 
   3=>           '2,3', 
   4 =>           '1,2,4', 
   5 =>           '1,3', 
   6=>           '2,3',
   7 =>           '1,3',
   8  =>           '1,2,3,5',
   9 =>           '1,2,3');

$produCt =array();
foreach ($array1 as $index =>$val){ 
   $arra = explode(',', $val);
    if(count($arra)>2){
         for($i=0;$i<count($arra);$i++){
             for($j=$i+1;$j<count($arra);$j++){
                 $produCt[] = $arra[$i].",".$arra[$j];              
             }              
           }
    }else{
      $produCt[] =$val;
    }
}
$prdtCount =array_count_values($produCt);
var_dump($prdtCount);
```

I assume that your required output is

```
array (size=8)
  '1,2' => int 4
  '1,5' => int 2
  '2,5' => int 2
  '2,4' => int 2
  '2,3' => int 4
  '1,4' => int 1
  '1,3' => int 4
  '3,5' => int 1
```

Comment: how about if the ItemSet is 3 or more?
   `ItemSet`  
   `1,2,3`  
   `1,2,4`  
   `1,2,5`  
   `1,3,4`  
   `1,3,5`  
   `1,4,5`  
   `2,3,4`  
   `2,3,5`  
   `2,4,5`  
   `3,4,5`

Comment: that is the answer that I am looking for, but for all possible combinations.

Comment: I am making the ItemSet into all the combinations possible from 1-5 meaning from Itemset 1 to Itemset 1,2,3,4,5 combinations. Sup. cont counts how many times 1 appears in the Itemset then 1,2 then 1,3,4 then 1,3,4,5 and lastly when all the combinations are complete all five digits.